# Jetpack Compose - UI performance issues as lines grow in Canvas

Tags: android, kotlin, canvas, android-jetpack-compose

```
data class Line(val start: Offset, val end: Offset, val color: Color = Color.Black, val strokeWidth: Dp = 5.dp)
    
@Composable
fun App(){

    var lines = remember { mutableStateListOf<Line>() }

    Canvas( modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().pointerInput(Unit) {
        detectDragGestures { change, dragAmount ->
            change.consume()
            val line = Line(
                start = change.position - dragAmount,
                end = change.position,
                color = strokeColor,
                strokeWidth = strokeWidth
            )

            lines.add(line)
        }
    }
    ) {
        lines.forEach { line ->
            drawLine(
                color = line.color,
                start = line.start,
                end = line.end,
                strokeWidth = line.strokeWidth.toPx(),
                cap = StrokeCap.Round
            )
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code for a painting app and the problem is straight forward, as my lines list grows as I draw, the UI starts lagging and hits performance bottle neck since I am iterating over lines which calls drawLine method on every recomposition.

While there's no single silver bullet solution to this I tried various methods to resolve this but to no avail. Any help would be nice since my app is facing ASO issues due to this bottleneck.

Note- Keeping a history of lines helps me in implementing a rewind functionality, so don't want to modify core structure of the codebase.

Comment: you can try accumlating lines in a path add all of the lines to path and draw the path instead of drawing for each line. Something like  `val path = Path()

    lines.forEach { line ->
        path.lineTo(line.start.x, line.start.y)
        path.lineTo(line.end.x, line.end.y)
    }

    drawPath(
        path = path,
        color = strokeColor,
        strokeWidth = strokeWidth.toPx(),
        cap = StrokeCap.Round
    )`

Comment: Maybe you can also try using the on of the other drawScopes, drawWithCache ?

Comment: You can use a `Path` as suggested (although you may run into other issues there), or drop to the native Android `Canvas` and use `drawLines()` (note the `s`). The batching of commands should greatly help. Note that both solutions only work if all lines have the same stroke width, so in practice you'd need one `drawLines()` (or one `Path`) per stroke width.